# Inner objects not being populated in MVC controller call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an object declared in my javascript which I would like to send to my controller. The object is of type `VMInterface` which looks like:

```
public class VMInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SourceID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public VMConnection VMConnection { get; set; }
    public List<VMInteraction> Interactions { get; set; }

}

public class VMConnection
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Connection { get; set; }
}

public class VMInteraction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<VMField> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class VMField
{
    public string InputOutput { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DataTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult UpdateVM(VMInterface vm)
{
    return null;
}
```

My call to the controller:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Admin/UpdateVM',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        Name: "Test Name",
        Description: "Test Desc",
        SourceID: 1,
        ProjectID: 4,
        VMConnection: {
            Connection: "IPAddress goes here",
            Username: "Username",
            Password: "Password"
        },
        Interactions: [{
            Name: "Method",
            Fields: [{
                InputOutput: "INPUT OR OUTPUT HERE",
                Name: "DROP LOCATION HERE",
                DataTypeID: 1
            }],

        }]
    },
    success: function (response) {
        //Do nothing
    }
});
```

I have double checked that all the field names match up and that the properties inside my `VMInterface` class are all public with `{ get; set; }`. My call is hitting my controller ok and all of the top level (ei `Name`, `Description`, `SourceID` and `ProjectID`) fields map correctly. However for my `VMConnection` and `Interactions` field the information is not being populated.

[image]
[image]

Is there anything I'm missing to get these mapped correctly?

Comment: You need to stringify the data - `data: JSON.stringify{ vm: data }` and set `contentType: 'application/json',` or alternatively name the properties to match your model using dot notation e.g. `VMConnection.Connection: 'IPAddress goes here'` and `Interactions[0].Name: 'Method' etc

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately neither of them worked. The 1st method returned null for everything and the 2nd method threw errors in Visual Studio

Comment: Then you did not do it right!

Comment: :) ? http://i.imgur.com/sERyik7.png http://i.imgur.com/lib2rWi.png

Comment: Method 1: your missing the `{ vm: yourData }` as per my comment

Comment: I think I'm missing something regarding syntax, I've got data: JSON.stringify{ vm: data } but VS keeps saying `Expected ')'` http://i.imgur.com/QjRBNM6.png

Comment: Give me another 10 min :)

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ vm: { Name: "Test Name", .... }}` but its needs to be a `type: 'POST',` and the method needs to be `[HttpPost]` (other wise you need option 2 and that would create a really ugly query string.

Comment: Are you really hard coding a javascript like that in the view. I assume its just for testing and that you really are wanting to post values from a form, in which case you can just use `$('form').serialize();` to serialize you form assuming the view is generated correctly

Comment: Indeed I was hardcoding it for testing; the original version was a populated javascript object being passed back to my controller. Thank you very much for your response, I'll give that a try now

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, that's worked!! If you could then I will mark that as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your sending data to a GET method, the values must be generated as as a query string which means the the name/value pairs must match you model structure. The property name needs to be in the same dot notation that you would use to access the property in the server.

If you wanted to get the value of `InputOutput` in the first `VMField` of the first `VMInteraction` in your POST method, you would use

```
var value = vm.Interactions[0].Fields[0].InputOutput
```

Since the name of the parameter is `vm`, just strip that prefix and that is how you data needs to be, so you ajax call would be

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    data: {
        Name: "Test Name",
        Description: "Test Desc",
        ....
        VMConnection.Connection: "IPAddress goes here",
        VMConnection.Username: "Username",
        ....
        Interactions[0].Name: "Method",
        Interactions[0].Fields[0].InputOutput: "INPUT OR OUTPUT HERE",
        ....
    },
```

Note that this will create an ugly query string, and there is a risk that you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception, so using `type: 'Post',` and marking the method `[HttpPost]` would be more appropriate.

The other alternative is to use your javascript object as it is, stringify it, and send it as `contentType: 'application/json'`. This means that it must be a POST, since as GET has no body. Your ajax call will then be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Admin/UpdateVM',
    type: 'Post', // must be a post
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8', // set contentType
    data: JSON.stringify(vm : { // stringify the data
        Name: "Test Name",
        Description: "Test Desc",
        SourceID: 1,
        ProjectID: 4,
        VMConnection: {
            Connection: "IPAddress goes here",
            Username: "Username",
            Password: "Password"
        },
        Interactions: [{
            Name: "Method",
            Fields: [{
                InputOutput: "INPUT OR OUTPUT HERE",
                Name: "DROP LOCATION HERE",
                DataTypeID: 1
            }],

        }]
    }}),
```

and change the method to be `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Great answer, really thoroughly explained! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this.

**Action Method:**(HttpGet to HttpPost)

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult UpdateVM(VMInterface vm)
 {
       return null;
 }
```

**Javascript:**

```
  var myData = {
            Name: "Test Name",
            Description: "Test Desc",
            SourceID: 1,
            ProjectID: 4,
            VMConnection: {
                Connection: "IPAddress goes here",
                Username: "Username",
                Password: "Password"
            },
            Interactions: [{
                Name: "Method",
                Fields: [{
                    InputOutput: "INPUT OR OUTPUT HERE",
                    Name: "DROP LOCATION HERE",
                    DataTypeID: 1
                }],

            }]
        }

  $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/UpdateVM',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),                   
            success: function (response) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        });
```

It's working fine !!!!!!!